# Can I use "The question then arises" to pose a question and give an answer myself? I am writing the introduction to technical report

Tags: questions

The text is as follows:

> However, such technicalities have sophisticated these structures, because they are now more dependent on the individual behavior of their multiple components that they are made of, and each of these could affect the functionality of the structure. The question then arises as to how we could build a structure that is least affected by its separate parts and has the ability to adjust if any particular part malfunctions. Hence, to improve the reliability of any structure, we require the concept redundancy.

Also, can I know a better connecting clause that is better suited than "hence".

Comment: Speaking of redundancy--the phrase "that they are made of" is redundant after *components,* as is "the concept" before *redundancy.* Also, the verb *sophisticate* is seldom used in the active voice any more.

Comment: Not the best choice, because you're following on from what _has_ happened. You would be better using 'So the question now arises ...' or 'The question thus arises ...'.

Answer (score 1):

1.Yes, -- 2. *Hence* is fine but you can use *Thus* or *So* -- 3. What is a “concept redundancy”? -- 4. I would avoid the verb “to sophisticate”: it has several meanings and not all of them are appropriate.

Comment: "not all of them are appropriate" - indeed.